# Angular mat table disable buttons based on the data

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, mat-table

I have a table with 4 cols ( id, document , status and edit) . 3 values come from an api call

when the table loads what I need done is each row must check the status value and if it false disable the button

I using reactive forms

Please can someone help

Comment: Show us the code of your table?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply disabled any button conditionally using `disable` property binding like below -

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items'>
....
   <button [disabled]='!item?.status'>Edit</button>
...
</div>
```